# Styles.xml not found in IntellIJ 15 Android project?

Tags: java, android, xml, intellij-idea

I have started using IntellIJ Idea 15 with Android SDK for Android Development instead of Android studio. But in the  **res > values**  folder, I couldn't find the file  **styles.xml**  as it is usually present in an Android Studio project. What's wrong?[image]

Comment: If it doesn't get automatically generated, then you could just make the file...